# implement public void edit(T entity) AbstractFacade java

Tags: java, facade

I´m trying to understand the facade pattern

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

using netbeans wizard, but I dont understand why send T entity to this void;

```
public void edit(T entity)
```

and no a id for this

```
public void edit(long id)
```

same for the remove method

```
public void remove(T entity)
```

and make this

```
public void remove(long id)
```

how can I implement the void Edit in my bean controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly:

> Why `send(T entity)` returns `void` and doesn't require ID?

Because `entity` passed as argument already contains ID and will overwrite entity which have the same ID in DB table

> Same for the `remove(T entity)` method

Same for this. If you don't have an entity, just ID, then to remove entity by ID, you need to create new empty entity, assign ID and pass it to `remove()` method.

> how can I implement the void Edit in my bean controller?

Here, you don't need to implement anything except `getEntityManager()` method. Kind of:

```
public class MyFacade extends AbstractFacade<MyEntityClass> {

     @Resource
     EntityManagerFactory emf;

     @Override
     EntityManager getEntityManager() {
         return emf.createEntityManager();
     }
}
```

Comment: yes sasha,  and how do i get the id to edit, my single record??